# Can't shebang lines point to a hidden folder?

Tags: python, flask, terminal, shebang

I'm following [The Flask Mega Tutorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world) for the second time. However, I'm using virtualenvwrapper and not virtualenv, and, contrary to where the author decided to put his python install directory inside a directory called flask inside his project directory (so his is root_directory/flask/bin/python), my Python install is inside a hidden folder (`.virtualenvs`) in my OS X user home directory.

The problem is, trying to execute the file `run.py`, which is in the project's root directory, is failing with the following shebang line:

```
#!flask/bin/python
from app import app
app.run(debug=True)
```

I have made multiple attempts to change the shebang line appropriately, but I can't seem to get it right. The error is "no such file or directory exist."

So the full path to **my** Python install is:

```
/Users/me/.virtualenvs/get_env_details
```

And **my** project root directory, which is also where `run.py` is, is this:

```
/Users/me/PycharmProjects/projectname/
```

Note that virtualenvs folder is a hidden folder. Is that the culprit? For the record I'm trying to execute `run.py` from Pycharm, while the virtual env is activated.

Comment: Just use `#!/usr/bin/env python`, the virtualenv will handle the rest.

Comment: @jonrsharpe! This worked. Can you explain why/how does virtualenv handle this itself?

Comment: use `/usr/bin/env` in bash console before and after you activate `virtualenv` and you will see difference. And you can check also `/usr/bin/env --help`